# Matlab and QT figure integration

Tags: c++, matlab, qt, mex, qtopengl

I write a c++ file that opens a qt widget, and wrapped it with mex so I can call it from Matlab. Is it possible to open the widget withing a figure? e.g. in a subplot axes?

Comment: Should be doable, but implementation might be OS-specific. For example on windows we embed Matlab figures in a WPF application by creating a Matlab figure, using FindWindow to find the window of class SunAwtFrame, then embed it using SetWindowLongPtr to make it a child window and then SetParent..

Comment: Can you post/point to reference code? Not sure how to handle the sunAwtFrame w.r.t qtwidget?

Comment: I only have code using plain HWND (similar to what can be seen here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22842901/How-is-the-owner-of-a-win32-window-changed.html) so nothing QT-specific. However there's QWidget::winId() which gives a HWND so that might be usable. I don't have QT installed though, nor mex code which I can use to test. However if you're ok with a windows-only, untested answer I can post it.

Comment: Go for it, I'll use it as reference and will post a working copy once ready

Comment: Sorry going through the code I just realized what I have does the opposite (embed entire matlab figure in another window) of what you want (embed qt widget in matlab plot) so it won't be of much use I think: matlab subplots etc don't have their own HWND but are Java widgets or so and I don't know how to access those, let alone modify them. If the Qt wiget you have has static content, it's going to be *way* easier to have your C++ function return an image or so and then just use imshow() in Matlab.